# Qt5 UI not showing unchecked cells of table widget in python app

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I'm begining with Python. I'm developing a simple desktop app to print a control check of motorcycles services. The problem is that the UI not showing the unchecked checkboxes in the table when I run the script

**Screenshot with errors in red**

[image: Errors in red]

**Screenshot with cells configuration in Qt5 Designer**

[image: Qt5 UI]

**The code**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class ServiceLabeler(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServiceLabeler, self).__init__()
        loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.btnPrint.clicked.connect(self.printLabel)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def printLabel(self):
        print('Printing ...')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = ServiceLabeler()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to see the main.ui code please follow next link to gist
https://gist.github.com/CristalT/0d2e5cc2c684c6dc2b87bd5ec1d7348e

Comment: share the main.ui

Comment: @eyllanesc I pasted a link to share it.

Comment: I see that it is a bug, so there are 2 solutions: you convert the .ui to .py or by code you enable it to be checkeable.